# Call method inside keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, this

I'm dev a jquery plugin and i'm using this boilerplate [jqueryboilerplate](http://br.jqueryboilerplate.com/), my plugin is refered to textarea and i'm calling keypress event like that

```
init: function(){
  $(this.element).keypress(function(){
    alert('hey');
  });
},
```

so this alert is working right, so inside keypress he can't see my local methods like that.

```
init: function(){
  $(this.element).keypress(function(){
    this.sayHey();
  });
},
sayHey:function(){
  alert('hey');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the key press callback, the value of `this` is no longer referencing your plugin object. Try using the `that` trick like this:

```
init: function(){
  var that = this;
  $(this.element).keypress(function(){
    that.sayHey();
  });
},
sayHey:function(){
  alert('hey');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use the [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to pass a custom context to event callback function

```
init: function(){
    $(this.element).keypress($.proxy(function(){
        this.sayHey();
    }, this));
},
sayHey:function(){
    alert('hey');
}
```

Or better there is no need to create an anonymous function here

```
init: function(){
    $(this.element).keypress($.proxy(this.sayHey, this));
},
sayHey:function(){
    alert('hey');
}
```